# @page background-image depending on class?

Tags: css, printing, mpdf

I have two different pages/nodes on a site that I want to have different @page rules for background-image in my CSS. I'm not very familiar working with print-rules in particular (though I work daily with CSS), therefore I'm not sure how to accomplish this

I've tried to put @page with the likes of `body.node-type @page{}` but that does nothing. Is this even possible, or is @page impossible to pair with a class or id – in that case, how do I solve this?

Edit, tried below but didn't work either:

```
body.node-type-reference{
     @page {
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I maybe could put the background image in a separate div, but that would require major rework of the code and I'm not even sure if that'd play nice when overflowing to the second page (since the first page is unique from the rest in both node-types).

Comment: why don't you give each page a different class name on one of it parents divs?

Comment: I have, question is how can I select it with the @page attribute?

Comment: In lack of better implementation I've now put the @page rule within a <style> tag on the node-type in question – ugly but functional. Replies on better solutions are still welcome. EDIT: scratch that, it didn't work to full extent either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this within the `@page` at-rule alone. CSS does not support conditional `@page` at-rules with conditions that depend on matching selectors within the markup.

As you've found, this is worked around by including the specific `@page` at-rule in a `<style>` embedded in just the page you want the rule to apply (given that the class you're matching is on the `body` element, which is usually indicative of document-specific styles).

Comment: Ah, alright. The only problem is  that I rely on a module to generate pdf-documents from the content on the pages which only takes one print.css file. Ugh, looks like I have some major rework ahead of me.